# How use dash in Typescript declaration file for JSON data?

Tags: json, typescript, types

After loading a JSON file in my Typescript app I use an interface to get code completion in the IDE for the JSON data:

```
interface Component {
    name:string
}
```

That works, but the JSON also contains a property `en-US` which has a dash... that's not allowed in an interface... how can I fix this?

```
{
    "name" : "boink",
    "en-US" : "hello there"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set attributes in quotes inside your interface like:

```
interface Component {
    'en-US': string;
}
```

But you should be aware that you have to select the property via quotes each time you want to use it:

```
 let myComponent: Component = {
     'en-US': 'hello there'
 }
 let translation = myComponent['en-US'];
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. Is there a way to make the property optional, as in `locked? : true` where the property `locked` is optional. If I use a ? with `'en-US'? : string` it doesn't work.

Comment: For me `'en-US'?` works fine (using typescript 2.4,2)